# Regex to first match, then replace found matches

Tags: c#, regex

In my C# program I am using Regular expressions to:

- Loop through a list of possible words in need of replacing.
- For each word, to find out if a string I am given has any matches.
- If it does, I perform some (slightly costly) logic to create the replacement.
- I then perform the actual replacement.

My current code looks roughly as follows:

```
string toSearchInside; // The actual string I'm going to be replacing within
List<string> searchStrings; // The list of words to look for via regex

string pattern = @"([:@?]{0})";
string replacement;

foreach (string toMatch in searchStrings)
{
    var regex = new Regex(
                            string.Format(pattern, toMatch), 
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                            );
    var matches = regex.Matches(toSearchInside);

    if (matches.Count == 0)
        continue;

    replacement = CreateReplacement(toMatch);

    toSearchInside = regex.Replace(toSearchInside, replacement);
```

And I can get this working, but it seems somewhat inefficient in that it is using the regex engine twice - Once to find the matches (`regex.Matches()`) and once for the replacing `regex.Replace()`). I was wondering if there was a way to simply say *replace the matches you already found*?

Comment: You are not assigning the results of `Replace` to anything.  Shouldn't it be `toSearchInside = regex.Replace(toSearchInside, replacement);`?  Also you might want to consider using `Regex.Excape` on `toMatch` if it might contain special characters, unless you want them to behave as part of the regular expression.

Comment: Yes, @juharr, you're 100% right, this is just some pseudo-code I wrote to explain the situation. Thank you!

Comment: Create a regex with all the words you want to replace. Create a hash list, where key is the word to replace. Use the regex in a delegate replace. Return the hash value given the matched key. It's the fastes way to do it. You can create a regex of the search words using the ternary tool from [here](http://www.regexformat.com). Ternary tool [screenshot](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg). Creates a full regex trie.

Comment: @sln Only down side is that `CreateReplacement` would have to be called for each search string even if said search string is not a match to create the hash list.  So really depends on how often the same collection of search strings are used to determine if caching them would be worth it.

Comment: Knowing what the CreateReplacement does is crucial to answer this question. I suspect all the necessary things can be done inside a Match evaluator.

Comment: Should this be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @juharr - I don't see anything variable in the relationship of `toMatch` in the creation of a regex, nor in `CreateReplacement(toMatch)`. Unless `toMatch` is dynamically dependent on an operation that occurs in the middle (body) of the `foreach ()` block, it is nothing but a static list of searchStrings. In that respect, the regex stuff could be taken out of the body, and a `foreach() { CreateReplacement(); }` is all that is needed to create the hash list ahead of time. It took me a half second to this conclusion when I first read the post. Still the fastest way to do it is as I described.

Answer (score 0):

you could get all the matches from the first match - and for each match you have its index, that you could iterate through the matches and replace it in the string itself - since it is more efficient than regex replace.

Though I would measure the performance with small unit test ( and having NCrunch running in background makes it faster)